# Command is invoked only if user press on particular area of button content

Tags: wpf

I am a newbe on wpf. I need a control like that
[image]

It should work like a button. It should change background color on IsMouseOver and on IsPressed. But click should be triggered and command invocked only when user clicks the cross. Is there a way to restrict clickable area for button with providing some custom content or template?

Comment: For all elements in your template (or custom control) which should not react to mouse click, try setting their `IsHitTestVisible` property to false. (Make sure that those elements that should react to mouse do keep `IsHitTestVisible` being true)

Comment: You're going about this the wrong way.  Don't try and make a button with a custom clickable area, make a composite control -- for example a text block and a button laid out in a grid with two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to make a whole button-control with just a "partly"- button I would instead do it with a stackpanel or grid.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Textblock>Some Text</Textblock>
  <Button source="YourImage"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Now you can decide width,heigt and those properties you see fit. To make your Textblock and button to change background if the mouse is over, I would look over `Style`'s and `Trigger`'s

[Here is a link to a tutorial](https://www.wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html)